# Reactjs: hide or show components based on api response

Tags: reactjs

so I have an API that returns true or false, based on if the store is open. I want to implement a logic inside a class component such that it will render different component if the store is open, and hide a specific component if the store is closed. If possible i want to do it using className, i just want to hide a class when the store is closed.

Comment: Please add minimal code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have not done anything yet I am sorry, basically I want to fetch the API, based on the response is true or false, I want to show/hide components

Comment: `const Component = (apiResult) => apiResult ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />`

Comment: can I write this inside a render component? I have an error when I write const inside the { } inside render method